# how to retrieve field value (values are itself string)in given line using regular expression in python

Tags: python

I am newbie to python,i am facing below issue please help me:

I read line by line from one file, each line having field name and its value,
now  i have to find out field name and filevalue in the line.example of line is:

```
line=" A= 4 | B='567' |c=4|D='aaa' "
```

Since some field values are itself a string so I am unable to create regex to retrieve field name and filed value.

Please let me know regex for above example. 
the output should be

```
A=4 

B='567'

c=4

D='aaa'
```

Comment: Can the strings contain quotes or the | mark?

Comment: i have recodrd of data A= 4 | B='567' |c=4|D='aaa'  in file which i am reading line by line

Comment: That's not the question; I've asked whether the sting can contain | marks or quotes, for instance: A=4 | B="|" | C='"' and so on. If so, what's the escape character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
import re

line = " A= 4 | B='567' |c=4|D='aaa' "
re.search( '(?P<field1>.*)=(?P<value1>.*)\|(?P<field2>.*)=(?P<value2>.*)\|(?P<field3>.*)=(?P<value3>.*)\|(?P<field4>.*)=(?P<value4>.*)', line ).groups()
```

output:

```
(' A', ' 4 ', ' B', "'567' ", 'c', '4', 'D', "'aaa' ")
```

you can also try using \S* instead of .* if your fields and values do not contain whitespaces. this will eliminate the whitespaces from output:

```
re.search( '(?P<field1>\S*)\s*=\s*(?P<value1>\S*)\s*\|\s*(?P<field2>\S*)\s*=\s*(?P<value2>\S*)\s*\|\s*(?P<field3>\S*)\s*=\s*(?P<value3>\S*)\s*\|\s*(?P<field4>\S*)\s*=\s*(?P<value4>\S*)', line ).groupdict()
```

output:

```
{'field1': 'A',
 'field2': 'B',
 'field3': 'c',
 'field4': 'D',
 'value1': '4',
 'value2': "'567'",
 'value3': '4',
 'value4': "'aaa'"
}
```

this will create related groups:

```
[ re.search( '\s*([^=]+?)\s*=\s*(\S+)', group ).groups( ) for group in re.findall( '([^=|]*\s*=\s*[^|]*)', line ) ]
```

output:

```
[('A', '4'), ('B', "'567'"), ('c', '4'), ('D', "'aaa'")]
```

does it help?

Comment: You don't create a link between keys and values, e.g. `A` is not related to `4`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is converting each line into a dictionary. I assume that you don't have any quote marks or `|` marks in your strings (see my comments on the question).

```
result={}                      # Initialize a dictionary
for line in open('input.txt'): # Read file line by line in a memory-efficient way
    # Split line to pairs using '|', split each pair using '='
    pairs = [pair.split('=') for pair in line.split('|')]
    for pair in pairs:
        key, value = pair[0].strip(), pair[1].strip()
        try:                     # Try an int conversion
            value=int(value)
        except:                  # If fails, strip quotes
            value=value.strip("'").strip('"')
        result[key]=value        # Add current item to the results dictionary
```

which, for the following input:

```
A= 4 | B='567' |c=4|D='aaa' 
E= 4 | F='567' |G=4|D='aaa'
```

Would give:

```
{'A': 4, 'c': 4, 'B': '567', 'E': 4, 'D': 'aaa', 'G': 4, 'F': '567'}
```

Notes:

- If you consider `'567'` to be a number, you can strip the `"` and `'` before trying to convert it to integer.
- If you need to take floats into account, you can try `value=float(value)`. Remeber to do it after the int convertion attempt, because every int is also a float.

Comment: You are not using regexp; According to the question, Please let me know regex for above example.

Comment: If there's a simpler Pythonic solution, why force regex?

Comment: because it is in the question. you don't know why he wants to use re. maybe exercise? I do not judge questions, I answer them if I know the answer.
btw your solution is not simpler than re in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have nasty things like nested quotes or unmatched quotes you can do it all with `split` and `strip`:

```
>>> line = " A= 4 | B='567' |c=4|D='aaa' "
>>> values = dict((x.strip(" '"), y.strip(" '")) for x,y in (entry.split('=') for entry in line.split('|')))
>>> values
{'A': '4', 'c': '4', 'B': '567', 'D': 'aaa'}
```

Comment: While I agree about not necessarily needing a regex, IMHO that's a rather complicated expression to throw at a Python newbie wouldn't you agree? Regardless, it would a easier for everyone to comprehend your answer if you limited the length of your lines of code so scrolling wasn't necessary to read it.

Comment: You treat numbers as strings; According to the question, `c=4` and not `c='4'`.

Comment: @Adam Matan - good point.  Your answer fixes this so I've just upvoted that rather than fixing mine.